# Присвоение данных из другого файла MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть база MySql OpenCart, в ней указанны неправильно ссылки на фотографии к товарам. 
В этой таблице, MySql - указаны ID товара, наименования и ссылки.
Есть второй файл, не MySQL, а XLS, в нем только названия и правильные ссылки на фотографии. 
Как в MySQL файле присвоить правильные ссылки в соответствии с названиями товаров?

Answer (score 0):

Экспортировать из Excel в CSV, загрузить во временную таблицу и выполнить обновление.

Comment: Для умственно-отсталых, как я, можете описать алгоритм? 
Или связаться со мной как нибудь, что бы показать на пальцах?

Comment: То, что написано, и есть алгоритм. С моей точки зрения - и полный, и подробный. Дальше - только "сделайте за меня".

Comment: @kff Если это не ответ на вопрос, то и вопрос некорректный, по сути. Нет примеров попыток сделать что-то самому, а есть только "расскажите/покажите". На вопросы после того, как описали алгоритм действий, хочется посылать в гугл. Извините за оффтопик (